# Restrict PHP Script's Access To Other Directories

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am building a web application that will allow users to install plugins just like WordPress.

I don't want the scripts in the plugin directory to be able to access the parent directories. This is how the directory structure will look like:
[image]

I am running PHP on Apache server on a Linux operating system. I am on a VPS server. :)

Comment: did `deny from all` ? in `.htaccess` work?

Comment: I want to disable PHP script's access to parent directories. Adding `deny from all` in `.htaccess` will stop users from accessing them